# How do I redirect to a different page after clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying using socket io and node to display two htmls. I have:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.html")
})
```

which the user logs in and hits the login button. This sends a signal back to the server. Then, I want the server to send a different html page back to the user.
In the login.html, I have:

```
socket.emit('username', $('#username').val());
```

which is receive by the server:

```
    socket.on("username", function(username){
            res.redirect(__dirname + "/index.html");
    })
```

However,  I can't use res because its null and the headers are already set from sendFile when the user reached the login.html page. How should I go about to send index.html(on the server) back to the user?

Answer (score 1):

You can emit a 'redirect' event from server side, listen to it on client side and have the redirection logic on client side

```
// server side pseudo code
socket.on("username", function(username){
      client.emit("redirect");
    })

// client side

server.on('redirect', function(){
   //redirect here
   window.location.href = /url here/
})
```